# How to perform TTest on multiple columns

Tags: python, statistics

My dataframe is below

```
patid age gender    tg0 tg1 tg2 tg3 tg4 wgt0 wgt1 wgt2 wgt3 wgt4
0   1   45  Male    180 148 106 113 100 198 196 193 188 192
1   2   56  Male    139 94  119 75  92  237 233 232 228 225
2   3   50  Male    152 185 86  149 118 233 231 229 228 226
3   4   46  Female  112 145 136 149 82  179 181 177 174 172
4   5   64  Male    156 104 157 79  97  219 217 215 213 214
```

Is it the right way If I do the average of `tg0 tg1 tg2 tg3 tg4` and `wgt0 wgt1 wgt2 wgt3   wgt4` so that i will get 2 columns a and b and do the ttest

Copying the case study also

> A physician is evaluating a new diet for her patients with a family history of heart disease. To test the effectiveness of this diet, 16 patients are placed on the diet for 6 months. Their weights and triglyceride levels are measured before and after the study, and the physician wants to know if either set of measurements has changed

Null hypothesis: There is no difference in the levels of Triglycerides and weight of individual after using new diet for 6 months.

Alt  hypothesis: There is has been a significant difference in the levels of Triglycerides and weight of individual after using new diet for 6 months.

For 2 variable we can do like below code

```
from scipy import stats
#Data of group 1
a = np.array([42.1, 80.0, 30.0, 45.8, 57.7, 80.0, 82.4, 66.2, 66.9, 79.0])
#Data of group 2
b = np.array([80.7, 85.1, 88.6, 81.7, 69.8, 79.5, 107.2, 69.3, 80.9, 63.0])
t2, p2 = stats.ttest_ind(a,b)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your issue is that you want to create t-test on both weight and triglycerids using one test? Could you not just split the test up into two test, and test the differences in weight and triglycerids using two t-test? If both the t-test for weight and the t-test for triglycerids show significance the null cannot be rejected?

Comment: I assume tg is Triglycerides and wgt is weight. Why are there four measurements of each per patient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find the difference before and after the 6 month period for each measurement type. Based on this, it seems that you would want to do two separate tests:

1. Whether the **final** triglyceride measurement value significantly differs from the **initial** triglyceride measurement.
2. Whether the **final** weight measurement value significantly differs from the **initial** weight measurement.

*Note: I'm assuming that each column represents a measurement over time, starting with 0 and ending with 4. This would mean that* `tg0` *and* `wgt0` *are the initial triglyceride and weight measurements respectively, and that* `tg4` *and* `wgt4` *are the final measurements*

For each test, you are comparing the final measurement with the initial measurement, so you would want to structure the tests like this:

```
t_tg, p_tg = stats.ttest_ind(tg4,tg0)
t_wgt, p_wgt = stats.ttest_ind(wgt4,wgt0)
```

Then use `p_tg` and `p_wgt` to make a unique determination for the triglycerides and the weight.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why there are four measurements of Triglycerides and weights for each patient.

Assuming that the measurements were taken lets say a month apart (while on the diet and tg0, wgt0 when starting the diet) then you could do one of two things:

1. Take the first and last values (tg0, tg4) and use those as the two groups (a, b). Do the same for wgt0 and wgt4.
2. To get better accuracy we can incorporate the other values by fitting a line of best fit through each patient's Triglycerides levels. And then using the first value of that line of best fit as `a` and last as `b` for each patient. Do the same for weights.

> Is it the right way If I do the average of tg0 tg1 tg2 tg3 tg4 and wgt0 wgt1 wgt2 wgt3   wgt4 so that i will get 2 columns a and b and do the ttest

If (tg0 tg1 tg2 tg3 tg4) are measurements before the diet and (wgt0 wgt1 wgt2 wgt3 wgt4) are measurements after and they are measuring the same thing (for example weight) then you could do what you propose.